# Firebase Promise in For Loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, firebase-realtime-database

I've a situation where I've to get the object based on each item in for loop, after getting that object I've to make another for loop to get object for that item. How to i create a promise for this? For reference, you can check my code below:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < children.length ; i++)
{    
  firebaseref =   firebase.database().ref(children[i]);
      var parentRef = firebaseref.once('value').then(function(snapshot){
        var childRef;
            if(snapshot.val().userRef!=undefined){
                  var keys = Object.keys(snapshot.val().userRef);
                  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length ; i++){
                        if(Is_static==true){
                          childRef = firebase.database().ref(keys[i]);
                        }
                        else{
                          childRef = firebase.database().ref(keys[i]);
                        }
                  childRef = childRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot){
                          var email = snapshot.val().email;
                          var mob = snapshot.val().mob;
                          if(email!=undefined && email!=""){
                            if(emails.indexOf(email)==-1)
                                 emails.push(email);
                          }else if(mob!=undefined && mob!=""){
                            if(mobile.indexOf(mob)==-1)
                                  mobile.push(mob);
                          }
                    });
                    promises.push(childRef);
                  }
            }
      });
      promises.push(parentRef);
 }
Promise.all(promises).then(function(results)
{             callAjax({EmailColl:emails,MobColl:mobile,Subject:sub,Message:message});
});
```

Comment: The problem is that when you `Promise.all(promises)` only the parentRef promise is there if you put the Promise.all(promises)` inside a `then` of the `parentRef` promise then things will work

Comment: If i put Promise.all(promises) inside then function, it is calling three times i mean each time the added promises of each iteration is completed